# Instant App Uploading APK is failed

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to add my APKs to Play Store but it gives an error :

**Upload failed
Your Instant App APKs contains an APK name 'productdetail' that either does not exist or was not included.**

Any idea why can it happen?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is "productdetail" in your app?

Comment: my feature module @thorin86

Answer (score 2):

A few things you could check here:

- Make sure you are uploading the ZIP file, and it does contain the `productdetail` APK. You need to upload all APKs at once.
- In your base module, you have `feature project(':productdetail')` in your `dependencies` section of your `build.gradle` file. (Modify the relative project path if product detail does not sit in the root folder of the project)
- In your instant apps project-level `build.gradle` (i.e. the one with `com.android.instantapp` plugin applied), you have `implementation project(':productdetail')` in your `dependencies` section.

Detailed explanation of project structure could be found here: https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/structure.html

I would also recommend checking out Hello World code samples from https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/samples.html and compare your `build.gradle` against the samples to spot mistakes in build files.